# Configure smtp for Episerver Forms

Tags: episerver

Is there any easy way to configure smtp for episerver forms? (iam using 4.0) 
I want the form owner and potentially the user to get a confirmation mail.

**Update**
I tried to add a smtp settings in web.config

```
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="***" password="***" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And in episerver the form is configured:
[image]
I dont know if it should work, but i decided to read the logs and its complaining:

```
System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
   at EPiServer.Forms.Implementation.Actors.SendEmailAfterSubmissionActor.SendMessage(EmailTemplateActorModel emailConfig)
```

However, its really hard to guess which string its complaining about since all ive done seems right to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it works. I dont know why i thought i could enter whatever i wanted at the "from" address. Make sure its a correct email address and it works just fine.
[image]

If you want an email address from a form field you can select it by its name like this.

[image]